# what does this output mean in YQL - PYTHON

Tags: python, yql

I am running this code with no error just can any body tell me what does the line bellow means? I get this as output of code:

```
    <yql.YQLObj object at 0x920c38c>
```

code is :

```
    import yql
    y = yql.Public()
    query = 'select * from geo.places where text="sunnyvale, ca"'
    y.execute(query)
```

Comment: It means `y.execute` returns an object. You're going to have to do something with the object to get the results of your query.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the result of query?? I did as here said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248007/doing-a-simple-yahoo-search-in-python?rq=1  but its not working

Comment: In what way is it not working? It would be good to edit your question to show how you tried to print it out and what error (or wrong output) you got.

Comment: I don't get any error ! I just don't know how to use the result !!! I want to know if "sunnyvale, ca" exists in geo.places or not !